# Unexpectedly low melting point of Aluminium

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements), the melting point of aluminium is 933.47K (660 ºC) while the melting point of magnesium is 923K (650 ºC), yet the melting point of sodium is merely 370.87K (98 ºC).

Huge difference between sodium and magnesium is expected, but small difference between magnesium and aluminium confused me.

Can anyone explain? Much appreciated

Comment: Hint: Melting points of bulk solids are mostly dependent on their **Crystal structure** and are not intrinsic properties of the atoms themselves.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb would you mind further explaining how structure affects the mp?

Comment: Hint: Why do solids have a structure? What is *between* the atoms in e.g. solid Al, or a diamond?

Comment: @Karl I understand that Bonding (or attractive force) are existed between the atoms, like Giant covalent structure of diamond gave it the property of high melting point. However, the question here is why Al has so little difference with Mg(with merely 10K), yet so large difference between Mg and Na

Comment: Due to my insufficient knowledge, I only know these 3 are all in giant metallic structures, with different degrees of ionization which indeed show the trend of increasing mp. I tried to find the crystal structure, while Mg is simple hexagonal, and Al is face-centred cubic, which I couldn't understand how these structures help to explain this odd feature that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: *Bonds* is the term we are looking for. Bonds are made of ... ?

Comment: I m sorry I cannot understand, are you saying electrostatic attractive force between opposite charged particles (positive metal cation and negative electron in metallic structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aluminium, Magnesium and Sodium form [Metallic Bonds](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Chemical_Bonding/Fundamentals_of_Chemical_Bonding/Metallic_Bonding) instead of Covalent bonds (like diamond, as discussed). The metallic bond strength depends on:

> 1. The number of electrons that become delocalized from the metal
> 2. The charge of the cation (metal).
> 3. The size of the cation.

Sodium has One delocalized electron as compared to Magnesium(2) and Aluminium(3). It's cation is also larger than Magnesium and Aluminium cations and also has a lower charge. This is why the strength of the metallic bond is lower in $\ce{Na}$ than it is in $\ce{Mg}$ and $\ce{Al}$ and hence the melting point is lower.

This also reflects in their crystal structure: $\ce{Na}$ has a body-centered cubic crystal with 68% packing efficiency whereas $\ce{Mg}$ and $\ce{Al}$ have a HCP and CCP structure respectively. Both these structures have a packing efficiency of 74%. This means that for a given unit volume, $\ce{Mg}$ and $\ce{Al}$ have more atoms in it as compared to $\ce{Na}$. This implies stronger bonds and  a higher melting point.